# new line in csv file dealing with spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark-sql

One of my input file is a csv (separated with comma). One of the field is address which has new line character in it. So this causes me considerable trouble when I read it using spark, where one input record gets split into muitiple records.

Has any one able to find a solution to deal with this. The workaround currently done is to remove the new line characters in data at source side before reading into spark.

I would like to create a general solution for this in spark. I use scala dataframe api's.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `multiLine` option of the csv reader.

```
spark.read.csv(file, multiLine=True)
```